# Trying to use JSON data to create buttons in HTML I've Tried Everything

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, appendchild

I'm trying to create an interactive menu from JSON data, so ultimately I want every item represented as a button. I'm having a lot of trouble converting the data to an HTML button.

The JSON data has been validated. I won't post all of it because it's over 1000 lines, but that doesn't seem to be part of the problem.

Below is my most recent attempt at using appendChild() and a for loop:

```
breakfast = {
    "Breakfast": [{
          "Pancakes": [{
              "item": "1 Pancake",
              "price": 2.00,

              "add-ons": {
                "blueberries": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "chocolate chips": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "M&Ms": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "Strawberry Topping": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "item": "2 Pancakes",
              "price": 3.00,

              "add-ons": {
                "blueberries": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "chocolate chips": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "M&Ms": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "Strawberry Topping": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "item": "3 Pancakes",
              "price": 4.00,

              "add-ons": {
                "blueberries": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "chocolate chips": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "M&Ms": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "Strawberry Topping": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "item": "4 Pancakes",
              "price": 5.00,

              "add-ons": {
                "blueberries": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "chocolate chips": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "M&Ms": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                },
                "Strawberry Topping": {
                  "add-on price": 0.50
                }
              }
            }
          ],

        }

//Snippet of massive JSON data

menuStart = document.getElementById("menuStart") //where the menu is placed on the page
function initiateBreakfast() {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(breakfast);
    var node = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(myJSON[i]);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    menuStart.appendChild(node);
    console.log(breakfast);
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help or insight.

Comment: How do you want the data displayed?

Comment: Ignoring brackets issues, `breakfast` in your code is an object, so while stringifying it is possible, it's pointless if you want to iterate over its contents. you're iterating over `data` but using the index `i` to access an element of `myJSON`; ignoring that that's a string now, this is still doomed to fail unless they happen to have the exact same number of elements

Comment: Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/5kLmn8yj/

Comment: What is `data`, and how does it relate to `breakfast`?

Comment: The 'data' variable was from a previous attempt at stringifying the contents, thats all fixed now. Thanks for the help, I think I got it now.